# UPDATE SQL Database

Tags: sql, insert

i have a store with prestashop script, i have many products and i want for all products select all carrier i have ad.
My table is like this:

```
id_product  id_carrier_reference    id_shop 
1                    3                 1
1                    8                 1
1                    12                1
2                    3                 1
2                    8                 1
3                    3                 1
4                    3                 1
```

And i want for all my prodcuts the 3 carriers 3, 8, 12). How to update this ?
Regards

Comment: If you want all unique `id_carrier_reference`, try `SELECT DISTINCT id_carrier_reference FROM myTable`. In case this isn't what you're trying to achieve, please try to clarify your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: For better help in your question, please include: 1) The query you've written that does not yet get results you want.  2) A table showing the desired results of your query, based on the sample data provided.  Currently, your question is too opaque.

Comment: ok, i just want update the database and ad the 3 carrire to all my products. i can do one by one but it's more long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to understand your question very well, but it seems that you want all records from `id_carrier_reference`, or only the first three records.

Will retrieve the first three records, 3, 8, 12 . If you want all the records, 3, 8, 12, 3, 8, 3 , 3 the remove the `LIMIT 3` from your query.

```
SELECT id_carrier_reference FROM table LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not english, maybe it's why you don't understand me :D. But anyways, i want have 3 / 8 /12 in id_carrier for all my products. With which sql request i can do it ?